# How do i add limit to to https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr so that i get only few records

Tags: reactjs, react-native, binance, binance-api-client

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price`,
        );
        const data: BinancePair[] = await response.json(); // Explicitly annotate the data type

        // Filter the results for symbols quoted in USDT
        const usdtPairs = data.filter((pair: BinancePair) =>
          pair.symbol.endsWith('USDT'),
        );
        setUsdtPairs(usdtPairs);
        console.log(usdtPairs);
        setLoading(true);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        setLoading(true);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

This is my code and the response array is too big and takes forever to display in my react native application, can we add some type of limit to this API so that we get 20 objects at first and then we have a load more button and by clicking that we get 20 more objects.

I tried various solutions to paginate on frontend but the load time was still too high

Comment: Are you sure the loading state is set correctly? Looks to me that the loading state is set to true when finished. The amount of data shouldn't really be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if that api is providing any inbuilt limiting  logic ,
like this `/api/data?page=1&pageSize=10` .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Symbol Price Ticker – Binance API Documentation](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#symbol-price-ticker) you can either select all tickers, as you do right now.

Select one ticker with `?symbol=LTCBTC` query parameter.

Or select several tickers with `?symbols=["LTCBTC","BNBBTC"]` query parameter.

As one way to paginate those, you can save all ticker names in your app and request 5-10 names per request with `?symbols=` query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`symbol` and `symbols` are introduced to reduce the number of tickers returned.